# Woocommerce "Add to cart" Buttons for each variable

Tags: button, woocommerce

Is it possible to create a seperate "Add to cart" button for each variable option within a WooCommerce product?

For example:

TShirt - Yellow - €99,- Add To Cart

TShirt - Blue - €99,- Add To Cart

TShirt - Green - €99,- Add To Cart

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check out the code in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38262109/383847). It creates a table for variable products.

Comment: Thanks! Found a link overthere pointing me in the right direction: www.eggplantstudios.ca/woocommerce-product-variation-add-cart-grid/